# Problem using `multi/http/mediawiki_thumb`, possibly due to the `Authorization` header

Tags: metasploit

My target requires the `Authorization` header with credentials to get into. I have the credentials but the module I'm using (`multi/http/mediawiki_thumb`) doesn't seem to have an option for `Authorization`.

I've tried setting `RHOSTS` to `user:pass@example.com` but that gives the error `[-] Exploit failed: One or more options failed to validate: RHOSTS.`.

I've also tried setting `HttpUsername` and `HttpPassword` to the respetive credentials, with `RHOST` as `example.com` and `TARGETURI` as `/` (I believe that's the root since it's the root of the files in [mediawiki](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki/), confirmed by running `gobuster` on files in the repository) but that gives me the error `[-] Exploit aborted due to failure: unexpected-reply: Couldn't find login token. Is URI set correctly?`.

What am I doing wrong here? Is it the URI or the `Authorization`?